# Why do we have to use $this-> operator? | PHP

Tags: php, oop

I'm developing an application in PHP. I am trying to figure out the use of $this-> and why it is always preferred.

I mean we can simply echo a property value inside a method using this code

```
<?php
class place{
    public $country;
    public function countryName($country){
        echo $country;
    }
}
$info = new place();
$info->countryName("Nepal");
?>
```

But, in examples I see that $this-> is used in this way:

```
<?php
class place{
    public $country;
    public function countryName($country){
        $this->country = $country;
        echo $this->country;
    }
}
$info = new place();
$info->countryName("Nepal");
?>
```

Is the use of $this-> preferred or is the first method totally normal?

Comment: `this` is not exclusive to PHP in the realm of OOP

Comment: the first method is not echoing any properties... you cannot compare the two codes.

Comment: @JayBlanchard, PHP handles `this` differently than other languages such as Java and C#. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353970/this-keyword-in-java-and-in-php

Comment: True @DarylBennett, but the concept of `this` is persistent throughout OOP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$this` is referencing to the current object.

As per php.net

> The pseudo-variable $this is available when a method is called from within an object context. $this is a reference to the calling object (usually the object to which the method belongs, but possibly another object, if the method is called statically from the context of a secondary object).

Answer (score 4):

```
$this->country
```

is country relative to the class

```
$country
```

is relative to the method

Answer (score 2):

`$this->country` will echo out your class level `$country` whereas just `echo $country` will echo out your method level `$country`. This is all because of how objects work in PHP and the scope of variables. As you keep looking you'll see the use of this a lot more

Answer (score 2):

The first arc isn't echoing a property it's just echoing the value that is passed in.

The second arc assigns the passed in value to the property, and then you use $this->country to echo the property.

If you echo $this->country in the first arc, you'll get nothing echo'd.

Answer (score 2):

```
$this->
```

Helps you refer to your class variables.

for example:

```
   public function countryName($country){
         $this->country = $country;
        echo $this->country;
    }
```

Your `$this->country` is referring to the class var, and it's needed to be set to the parameter `$country`.

Comment: Pardon me, it would appear that I'm mistaken. You can code without it in Java and other OOP, but it looks like in PHP you need to use `$this` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353970/this-keyword-in-java-and-in-php

Answer (score 2):

`$this` represents any instance of the class. So when you create an object `$USA` and call `countryName($country)`, `$this` will represent the object `$USA`:

```
<?php
$USA = new place();
$USA->countryName("USA");
?>
```

In your code, you are echoing the parameter of the function `countryName($country)` but not the class attribute, but here:

```
<?php
class place{
    public $country;//This is the class attribute.
    public function countryName($country){
        $this->country = $country;/*here you are storing the value of the parameter passed to the function into the class attribute ($this->country)*/
        echo $this->country;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The advantage to using  `$this->country` versus `$country`, is that you can use `$this->country` in other places as well. The value is stored in the object `$info`.

For example:

```php
// #1 case
class place {
  public $country; // This is not used
  public function countryName($country) {
    echo $country;
  }
}

$info = new place();
$info->countryName("Nepal");
// Result:
//   Nepal


// #2 case: Using $this
class place {
  public $country; // This is not used
  public function countryName($country) {
    $this->country = $country;
    echo $this->country;
  }
  public function whereAmI() { // NO parameters
    echo 'You are in the country "' . $this->country . '"';
  }
}

$info = new place();
$info->countryName("Nepal");
$info->whereAmI();
// Result:
//   Nepal
//   You are in the country "Nepal"
```